# How do I transfer my character to another server?

Tags: lost-ark

My friends play on a different server, and I foolishly created a character on another server and redeemed my founder rewards on that character.   Now that I've accumulated a decent amount of progress on the character, is there any way to transfer my character to another server, even if I can't keep my founder status and other associated bonuses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sources seem to indicate that this isn't possible:

[Rock Paper Shotgun](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/can-you-change-servers-in-lost-ark):

> **Unfortunately, you cannot change servers in Lost Ark.** When you make a character, they are linked to a server and cannot move to another.

[Dot Esports](https://dotesports.com/mmo/news/can-you-change-servers-in-lost-ark):

> That’s not the case in Lost Ark, however. Players can’t change servers in Lost Ark since it’s not allowed.

[Okay Gotcha](https://www.okaygotcha.com/2022/02/lost-ark-server-transfer-can-you-change.html):

> Is there a server transfer in Lost Ark? No, your character is currently tied to the server you created it on.

It seems the only way to get on the same server as your friends is if you make a new character on their server, or they make a new one on your server.

Comment: Is the comment under the question holding any truth at all? I've been looking through the shop -- maybe it's under a different name,  but I'm not sure if it's in there, or maybe I haven't reached endgame levels yet so it's not available to me?

Comment: @childe I have not found any information about transfer tickets.  There is a pretty nice comment posted on the forums by a community manager [here](https://forums.playlostark.com/t/there-must-be-free-transfers-now-if-character-creation-is-being-limited/62148/3) explaining why the feature of server transfers isn't a thing.  The overwhelming majority of posts indicate that at present, **there is no way to transfer a character to a different server**.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like to alleviate the situation they have allowed for a temporary time period where founders packs will transfer to the first character created on a new server, thank god for that.

Comment: the original Korean version still doesn't have a way to transfer characters. One was tested for a short while, but it "failed" and hasn't left the test phase since. So don't get your hopes up down the line for transfers to eventually open up. On the plus side the grind up to endgame is extremely fast and pretty easy so at most you dont lose much effort.